# consul not joining wan advertised wan nodes

Tags: consul

On my Datacenter A: I am advertizing wan ip of a node(10.8.0.1) inside vpn using consul config as show below:

```
{
"node_name": "rockpi-primary-server",
"bind_addr": "{{GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\"}}",
"ui": true,
"client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
"data_dir": "/tmp/consul",
"datacenter": "lon",
"log_level": "INFO",
"enable_syslog": true,
"enable_debug": true,
"server": true,
"bootstrap_expect": 1,
"leave_on_terminate": false,
"skip_leave_on_interrupt": true,
"rejoin_after_leave": true,
"advertise_addr": "{{GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\"}}",
"advertise_addr_wan": "{{GetInterfaceIP \"tun0\"}}",
"retry_join_wan": ["10.8.0.6"],
"retry_join": [
  "192.168.5.128",
  "192.168.5.166"
  ]
}
```

and in Datacenter B I have consul node (10.8.0.6) running with below config:

```
{
"node_name": "phl-remote-server",
"bind_addr": "{{GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\"}}",
"ui": true,
"client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
"data_dir": "/tmp/consul",
"datacenter": "phl",
"log_level": "INFO",
"enable_syslog": true,
"enable_debug": true,
"server": true,
"bootstrap_expect": 1,
"leave_on_terminate": false,
"skip_leave_on_interrupt": true,
"rejoin_after_leave": true,
"advertise_addr": "{{GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\"}}",
"advertise_addr_wan": "{{GetInterfaceIP \"tun0\"}}",
"retry_join_wan": ["10.8.0.1"]
}
```

but while monitoring datacenter A consul node I spotted this error:

```
2020-12-04T05:08:27.495+0530 [WARN]  agent: (WAN) couldn't join: number_of_nodes=0 error="1 error occurred:
    * Failed to join 10.8.0.1: dial tcp 10.8.0.1:8302: connect: connection refused
 
"
```

and similar for consul node on datacenter B

```
2020-12-03T23:34:19.548Z [WARN]  agent: (WAN) couldn't join: number_of_nodes=0 error="1 error occurred:
    * Failed to join 10.8.0.6: dial tcp 10.8.0.6:8302: connect: connection refused
 
"
```

what is wrong here ?
tun0 advertises vpn ip address of both the nodes. and firewall is node blocking

Comment: I think I just started facing something similar. Did you ever figure this out? I've tried fiddling and can't even get the previously working config running.